# How to make Visual Studio Handle HTML 5 Tags without warning

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, warnings

I have various html tags (related to jquery mobile) that Visual Studio is flagging as not valid attributes: For exmaple:

```
<div data-role="page" id="my_id" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
```

Gets amongst others:

```
Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'data-role'
is not a valid attribute of element 'div'
```

As you know, data-* are valid attributes of div in HTML 5.

I'm not sure how this is validated, though I think via DTDs and xmlns, so the head of the page is the default auto generated by Visual Studio:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I know they are only warnings, but my experience is that if you leave lots of warnings that are invalid, then all the warnings that are valid get lost in the middle.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio that these warnings should not be shown without completely disabling html validation?

(Visual Studio 2010 if it is relevant.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should install the [Web Standards Update](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingTheWebStandardsUpdateHTML5SupportForTheVisualStudio2010Editor.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29&utm_content=Google+Reader) and then switch to HTML5 as your default schema:

[image: The settings dialog for changing your default schema]

In addition, you should not use the XHTML 1.0 transitional opening incantation when using HTML 5 attributes. Instead, use the usual HTML5 one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Comment: What does Web Standards Update add to VS 2010 that it doesn't have without it?

Comment: My VS2010 has that HTML5 option without Web Standards Update installed. And the HTML5 attributes that i've tried do not have the red squiggly line in VS HTML editor when i set it to HTML5. But i did install Web Standards Update and then uninstall it. I didn't test it *before* i installed Web Standards. * shrug * I don't know what's up. Oh, well, at least it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2012 will be enough do uncheck 'Use doctype for validation schema detection'.

[image]

Comment: Why is not using the doctype to detect the doctype better than using the correct doctype?