# Attribute 'data-limit' is not valid attribute of element 'option' in aspx page in vs2013

Tags: jquery, html

The below warning message is coming.

`Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'data-limit' is not a valid attribute of element 'option'.`

I have also selected this option

`"Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML(Web Forms) -> Validation -> XHTML5 (selected)`

The following codes in index.aspx page.

```
<option value="<%: company.Uid %>" class="short" data-limit="52" title="<%: company.Country.Name + " " + "-" + " " + company.Name%>">
<%: company.Country.Name + " " + "-" + " " + company.Name%></option>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Visual Studio Handle HTML 5 Tags without warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447322/how-to-make-visual-studio-handle-html-5-tags-without-warning)

Answer (score 0):

[Switch to HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447322/how-to-make-visual-studio-handle-html-5-tags-without-warning) and then switch to HTML 5 instead of Transitional in your templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```